# onPostExecute is getting null result on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android

My code is perfectly working on upper version of Android. But whenever I am trying to run the program on Jelly Bean 4.2.2 its not working. My minimum SDK version is: 14 and target SDK version is: 22

My code is:

```
private class AuthAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0] + params[1]);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new    BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseTxt = null;
        HttpClient client = PaywellServices.getTrustedHttpClient();
        try {
            responseTxt = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseTxt;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            Log.e("Log","Try");
            Log.e("Result",result);
            if (result != null && result.contains("@")) {
                String splitedArray[] = result.split("@@@");
            }
       } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("Log","Catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you open internet when you test on device 4.2.2?

Comment: yap :) How can I forget that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, my phone is getting authentication error by Google. For that reason I was unable to get the expected response. After solving the Google authentication issue my code was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, **the result you return from doInBackground is passed to onPostExecute**.
So the **result** input parameter on **onPostExecute()** is the same String as returned in **doInBackground()** as **responseTxt**

At first glance, im thinking of this block of code in particular :

```
try {
    responseTxt = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
} catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return responseTxt;
```

As for debug, try to check the value (or print it to the console) of *responseTxt* before returning it.
My clue is that the result of the *PayWell* client is returning null when invoking the method in :

```
responseTxt = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
```

Comment: I tried the solution in both of my devices. While I connected one of my device in Kitkat version, the response was as desired. When I connected the Jelly Bean one, it got Null point exception. I have no clue why it is getting this. Before one week it was working on the Jelly Bean perfectly.

Comment: That is a relevant fact. 
Do like I told you and check if the Paywell client that you are instantiating (with PaywellServices.getTrustedHttpClient().execute()) returns a Null object. 
There is a good probability that the Paywell library/dependency recently changed and had its Jelly Bean support broken.
That is the clearest explanation I can see (without any stacktrace or complete code for review).
Try and check the value of the string or run the application in debug mode to confirm it.
Ill be glad to know what happened and help you

Comment: I have updated my SDK yesterday. Still getting the same problem. the same problem is occurring in my another app developed in another pc.

Comment: That basically proves that the problem is on the code. Do like I told you and double-check if "responseTxt = client.execute(request,responseHandler);" is null or not

Comment: that is null. nothing is passing from doInBackground

Comment: Because most likely your code is correct, and "HttpClient client = PaywellServices.getTrustedHttpClient();"  is either generating an exception, thus causing it to be null, or the result is null by default. Is there any stacktrace on the application? Can you post any of the stacktrace results here? I am curious about that Paywell library

Comment: I think the problem is in my device. My device is not able to get the response.

Comment: Does the Paywallet need access to the internet? If so, have you got all the permissions added to the manifest?

Comment: My problem is, my phone is getting authentication error by Google. For that reason I am unable to get the expected response.